# Shadow on left and right side

Tags: iphone, calayer, shadow

I am adding a shadow to a `CALayer` but I would like this shadow to only be on the left and right side of the view. Does anyone know if this is possible?

Currently, I am adding the shadow like this:

```
view.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
view.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0f, 0.0f);
view.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0f;
view.layer.shadowRadius = 4.0f;
view.layer.shadowPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:view.bounds].CGPath;
```

Comment: // Left Shadow 
view.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake( - 1.0f, 0.0f);

// Right Shadow 

view.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(  1.0f, 0.0f);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set the shadow path to the bounds of the view. Try getting that rect, and expanding it using `CGRectInset` (with negative x value, and 0 y value). This will give you a shadow path that expands beyond the left and right sides of the layer. You may need to tinker with the radius or inset the y value slightly to prevent the shadow appearing above and below.

Comment: I will have to set the frame to something like the following to hide the top and bottom frame. Problem with this is that the left and right shadows are also made smaller (not as high). `CGRect shadowFrame = CGRectInset(view.bounds, -1.0f, 7.0f);`

Comment: As I said, you may have to tinker with the radius as well. If it doesn't give you the effect you're after, you'll have to set a clipping path an draw the shadows manually, I think.